# IE11 Developer Tool Search Bar blocks after some searches

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, developer-tools

I'm having some trouble when trying to debug some javascript on IE. I use the search bar to find the functions I'm after, and in some cases the searchbar becomes disabled and the only way I can work with it again is if I close the browser and open it again.

[image]